# Problems with a specific filename in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

My `.gitignore` for this doesn't seem to be working:

```
*Previous.wtp
-- Previous.wtp
```

But I think that the rest of the exclusions work correctly in the file.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not an expert and I did search but it was hard to find a good concise list of `.gitignore` syntax.

The second line is the exact filename; it's in a subdirectory called Templates. Does that matter?

Comment: please say what you wish to accomplish..?

Comment: Is it already added to the index? you would need to remove it first (git rm --cached -- Previous.wtp)

Comment: There aren't any exclusions there. The first pattern matches `-- Previous.wtp` as well.  If you want the gitignore syntax, do `man 5 gitignore, [here's the online page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).

Comment: ah, VonC... you could be correct - I added it after I noticed that SourceTree was adding it to the Repository. However, now I would need to figure out the correct way to remove it from the cache in SourceTree, since I don't have git installed. I was thinking maybe the -- in the filename was messing things up but it could be just that it needs to be removed. What happened was I noticed that it was waiting to be staged in Source Tree (and so I added it to .gitignore after - but I'm not sure if I committed that file one time, I may have)

Comment: ah so "exclusion" means to exclude from ignore? I just was using the term as meaning "ignored files"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
subdirectory/Previous.wtp
```

where subdirectory is yours, obviously...